# adding a class to a link in a teaser using a hook

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, hook, hyperlink

I've been looking all day, but I just can't seem to get (any) hook working, this hook in particular. I want to use hook_link_alter to add a class (colorbox) to a link on a teaser. I was able to get it to work by hacking the core, but of course I would like a better solution.

the relevant code in node.module is :

```
if ($view_mode == 'teaser') {
$node_title_stripped = strip_tags($node->title);
$links['node-readmore'] = array(
  'title' => t('Read more<span class="element-invisible"> about @title</span>', array('@title' => $node_title_stripped)),
 'href' => 'node/' . $node->nid,    
  'html' => TRUE,
  'attributes' => array('rel' => 'tag', 'title' => $node_title_stripped),

);
```

}

I was able to achieve what I wanted by adding

replacing the last line (with text in it) with:      'attributes' => array('class' => 'colorbox' 'rel' => 'tag', 'title' => $node_title_stripped),

please help

Answer (score 1):

Following code will help:

```
function theme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // if readmore link is set
  if (isset($variables['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore'])) {

    // remove the old link
    unset($variables['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']);

    // Create new link variable
    $variables['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore-custom'] =  l(t('More >'), $variables['node_url'], array('attributes' => array('class' => t('colorbox'))));

  }
}
```

After that you need to add this new variable in node.tpl.php under your theme at appropriate place.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about hooks, but I would use Display Suite: http://drupal.org/project/ds

Make sure you also enable DS Extras, go to Structure->DS and create a CSS Class "colorbox"

Then go edit the content type, manage display, select "teaser", go to the bottom and create a layout (One column).

After saving, select the gear to the right of the link field and select "Expert" in the layout dropdown and "colorbox" in the classes select list.

Once you hit update and save, the field should be rendered with the class.

Comment: There's no gear icon next to the "Links" field unfortunately

Comment: Make sure "contextual links" module is enabled to display the gear.